# Some of the entries in SQL are empty and I don't want to print them

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to print only those entries that are not empty.

For example `amv=video1` and `vs=video2` and `vidbull` is empty and `vl` is empty. To print only amv and vs and if vidbull and vl is not empty they should also print automatically.

Check this image of my code:

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image of your code here with text, which you can (a) copy and paste, and (b) then use the code formatting tool button. This makes it much easier to read, and will allow other readers to copy and paste the code themselves, for example if they wish to try something out for you.

Comment: No pictures, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($amv != NULL){
     echo ''; //You have to print
}else if($vs != NULL){
     echo ''; //You have to print
}else if($vidbull != NULL){
     echo ''; //You have to print
}else if($vl != NULL){
     echo ''; //You have to print
}
```

Comment: @BuntyAmbarsaria If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.